# Filtering out data based effective and Term Data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have query contains both start and end date, i would like to filter out data based on two dates. I need only 2019 and higher data either based on start or end date, if you can have a look examples. i need ID 1,2,3,6,7 and 4,5 is not required. We can do based on extract year for both start and end date. but looking for better approach Thanks!

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP
(
ID INT,
SDate DATE,
EDate DATE
)

INSERT INTO TEMP
SELECT 1,'01/01/2014', '01/01/2019' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'01/01/2015', '01/01/2020' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'01/01/2019', '12/31/2019' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'01/01/2012', '12/31/2018' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'01/01/2010', '10/01/2016' FROM DUAL
 UNION ALL
SELECT 6,'06/01/2020', '10/01/2020' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 7,'01/01/2021', '03/01/2021' FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? *Sounds* like what you said, but - you didn't post how you do it now. If that's not "it", what "better" approach do you need and why? I mean, what's wrong with this?

```
SQL> select *
  2  from temp
  3  where extract(year from sdate) >= 2019
  4     or extract(year from edate) >= 2019;

        ID SDATE      EDATE
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 01/01/2014 01/01/2019
         2 01/01/2015 01/01/2020
         3 01/01/2019 12/31/2019
         6 06/01/2020 10/01/2020
         7 01/01/2021 03/01/2021

SQL>
```

Comment: Yeah it works sorry! i missed to one more entry, '6, '10/01/2020','12/31/2020'

Comment: Doesn't matter; both dates are in 2020 and won't fit.

Comment: yeah! i also need to fit that also

Comment: OK, no problem. I edited the answer as well. Have a look, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the condition on `edate` as follows:

```
select * from emp
where edate >= date '2019-01-01';
```

This will use the index on `edate`, if any.